# ModelAttribute аннотация в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Помогите разобраться,в первом методе мы добавляем `model.addAttribute(product)` во втором `@ModelAttribute("product") Product product` в чем разница и почему во втором методе редирект?

Как я понимаю, с этой аннотации `@ModelAttribute("product") Product produc`  в `editProduct.jsp` можем управлять моделью используя `${product.productPrice}`?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/editProduct/{id}")
public String editProduct(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    Product product = productDao.getProductById(id);
    model.addAttribute(product);
    return "editProduct";
}

// @ModelAttribute("product") we use as commandName on editProduct jsp in
// form!
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/editProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\image\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png");
    if (productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("no such product", e);
        }

    }
    productDao.editProduct(product);
    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model.addAttribute(product);
```

Предположим, что у Вас на странице `editProduct.jsp` есть таблица для приема `Product` и форма для отправки `Product` методом `POST`. Отсюда следует => когда Вы делаете `GET` - запрос на `"/admin/productInventory/editProduct/{id}"` - метод `editProduct()` берёт `id` продукта через `@PathVariable`, идет в базу по `id`, далее помещает полученный объект в `Spring Model` через `model.addAttribute()` и отправляет ее Вам на страницу. Если необходимо добавить в `model` новый атрибут с другим именем, то можно сделать так:

```
model.addAttribute("myFirstProduct", product);
```

Но учтите, что теперь принимающая jsp страница должна уже будет получить `${myFirstProduct}`.

Выше было сказано, что у Вас на странице есть  еще и форма, к примеру:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>

.....
какие-то данные
.....

//форма для POST
<c:url var="myPostAction" value="/admin/productInventory/editProduct"/>
<form:form action="${myPostAction}" commandName="product"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty product.id}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="productPrice">
                    <spring:message text="Цена"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="productPrice"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ......другие данные объекта product.......
            ......
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Отправить"/>"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Здесь `commandName="product"` - как раз и определяет объект, который будет отправлен данной формой  и будет получен в `ModelAttribute("product") Product product`  - и Spring соберет из формы объект.

А редирект в данном примере необходим для "чистого" нового запроса на `/admin/productInventory/editProduct`, что обезопасит от повторной отправки формы (а вдруг?). Подробнее по ссылке [redirect](http://javastudy.ru/patterns/pattern-prg-postredirectget-in-java/).

Comment: Но еще один вопрос,если я удаляю @ModelAttribute("product") Product product,програма работает как и работала,почему так?

Comment: В данном случае @ModelAttribute явно задавал имя атрибута (т.к. подобных объектов может быть несколько), иначе же без этой аннотации имя атрибута задается по умолчанию, по имени класса, т.е. User -> user; Product -> product. Могу порекомендовать эти ссылки: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc) , [два](http://thespringthing.blogspot.ru/2010/11/how-does-modelattribute-work.html), [три](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688135/modelattribute-annotation-when-to-use-it/26916920#26916920)